# Crontab not wrote into schedule after reboot and always restore to a specific time

Tags: cron, reboot, restore

I have a tiny computer, raspberry. It's a good computer. 
Recently, I got a problem when it run crontab and the problem is as this title. Otherwise, the system is always to restore. After editing crontab and then rebooting, when I checkout crontab schedule, it is still same as before.

What I do a test to proof crontab workable is to make a schedule as below:

`*/3 * * * * /bin/echo "hi" >> /home/test.txt`

(In every 3 minutes to generate "hi" to test.txt)

In addition, I add a file to a path such `touch test.txt`.It will disappear after reboot. So, I think the matter is on system restore.
Then, I found a curious matter on the "system time". It's always pegged on a specific system time. For instance, without internet connection, `user@host$ date` always restore to `Mon Nov 20 09:11:04 CST 2017` when I reboot the system.

Of cause, with internet connection, the system has the correct time displaying the current latest time.

I do more examination such as getting off apache2 service-`a2dissite mysite.conf`. When I reboot, the system restore to the specific system time I mention above. (without internet connection.)

Are there any clues about this matter?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your microSD card is OK? Try writing a file, rebooting and verifying the file is there. When cards fail, they go into a read-only mode. Everything seems to be working, but nothing is actually written to disk.

Comment: Thanks. What I have done it’s to unplug this card to my laptop. I found I couldn’t use fdisk, gparted and DiskUtility to format it. By this unsuccessful attempt, if you were me, how would you do this verification on this as card? I have backed up all of my data.

Comment: Try burning a new image to it. If it fails, I wouldn't risk using it. Some have reported success installing the card in an Android phone and formatting it, but even then, I wouldn't trust it with anything I really care about. I've written this up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I recall an implement tutorial as this article. The author move root file system to usb stick. However, I don't have an adequate size of stick on hand. It seems a choice to make it. I think I will get a new sd card to handle it.  
[link](https://samhobbs.co.uk/2013/10/speed-up-your-pi-by-booting-to-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your microSD card may have failed. On failure, most cards go into a read-only mode where everything appears to function, but no data is actually written. To test this, create a new file, reboot and see if the file is present. If not, you can try burning a new image to it. If that fails, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Some have reported success installing the card in an Android phone and formatting it, but even then, I wouldn't trust it with anything I really care about.

Comment: Hi, 
I buy a new card, SanDisk Ultra microSDHC UHS-I Card. It works well. I had copied the image from the old card, Transcend Premium 300x for backup. So, I am able to copy the backup to the new card, this SanDisk Ultra microSDHC UHS-I Card. The old card is completely failed with read-only mode. Thanks.